# Is it viable to daisy chain power across motor drivers?

Tags: power, schematics, motor-controller

I'm working on a hobby project where I want to run two DC motorss using [Adafruit DRV8871](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-drv8871-brushed-dc-motor-driver-breakout) motor drivers and a 7.2 NiMH battery. My idea is to daisy chain power from the first driver to the second, and then from that to an Arduino UNO for controller logic.

Here's my quick Fritzing sketch (the battery is a placeholder and I have not hooked up the signals yet):

[image]

So, is this an acceptable way to distribute power across the circuit?

If so, is it a *good* way to distribute power?

Comment: That doesn’t look like daisy chaining. If it were and one of the drivers were to fail everything would stop working. In your schematic you are actually using the battery to individually power the drivers using the connectors of one driver board since the battery probably does not have distribution rails. The good way would be to setup a distribution strip and then source power from there for the drivers.

Comment: Also not sure what voltage you are supplying to the Arduino. What is Vm?

Comment: @electrophile Right. So basically a parallell wire connection (new to the terminology here as you can see)? As for the voltage from Vm, that is also a bit unclear. Adafruit writes this: "This isn't the same as the logic level of the chip, which is up to 5.5 VDC. You do not have to provide a logic level power supply to the chip, how nice is that?"

Comment: @electrophile I think the Vm is actually the same as the motor power input which I suppose will make it 7.2 Volts. But the VIN pin on the Arduino should handle 7.2 volts, right?

Comment: Yes the Arduino VIN should be able to upto 9V.

Comment: @electrophile RIght. If you summarise this discussion as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That doesn't quite look like daisy-chaining. In daisy-chaining, if one element (in your case, the driver boards) were to fail, the whole chain would stop working. In your fritzing schematic, you are using the connectors of one of the boards to supply power to all boards, making it a parallel connection. I'm guessing this is because the battery does not have a distribution rail as such. This arrangement would work but to make it neater you could use a distribution rail connected to the battery and then use that to power everything else.

Second, the Arduino VIN can accept up to 9V. I've seen it work with as high as 12V too. Your battery voltage of 7.2V should be acceptable. That being said, I'm not aware of how the `Vm` is being derived from the main power source. If it is just being passed through the driver boards then this would work. However, if it is being 'processed' and then made available on `Vm` then any failure in the driver board would cut off power to the Arduino board.